# Mongodb Async vs Sync Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

I´m quite confused about java drivers for Mongodb. Reading the official [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.1/) it seems that you can use the normal MondoDB Driver or the MongoDB Async Driver.

The first question is: **Can I use both in the same application or I have to choose one?**

Trying to use the Async driver I found things that I used to do (with the normal driver) in which I get a bit lost now. For example, I used to do this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("my_coll").find(query);
String json = JSON.serialize(iterable);
```

And now I really don´t know how to convert the result into a json string since they have not included the `JSON` class from the Async driver.
Second question: **If I cannot use both drivers at the same time, how can I then serialize a `FindIterable<Document>`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are:

- Yes of course you can use both drivers. In fact, if you really care about performance in your application you should use the Sync driver for those actions that you need a response from MongoDB (like find()). And you will use the Async driver for the ones that you don't really need it, for "fire and forget" actions (like insert or update).
- So the serialization question gets answered from the above. If you get a response you are using the sync driver, therefore you can keep using `JSON` class:

`JSON.serialize(iterable);`

Comment: Sync is not going to offer a general performance advantage over Async, and neither will Async over Sync in general. The main advantage of choosing to use the Async driver is that it gives you the ability to perform overlapping queries. There are cases where if you have multiple queries to execute that contain no data dependencies on each other you can execute them asynchronously (overlapping) and await all their results together at a synchronization point.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be conscious of is that the two drivers share some dependencies.
Try to align the versions of the drivers such that they are both expecting the same version of their common dependencies otherwise you can end up with some ‘Class not found’ type issues resulting from the class loader picking an incompatible version of a class for one or other of the drivers.

I’d add that the use-case I found the async driver great for was a large export style query, where I had to return a large amount of data from a web service. In this case I had to return a large CSV. Previously this method would use up a lot of RAM building up the whole set of CSV data up before writing it to the client. Using the async driver I could read small batches (500 records at a time seemed optimal) from MongoDB and write them to the browser client in a chunked response.